# Display Submenus on hover and open link on Click

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I created a wordpress page. On the header menu when I click the page, it takes me to that page content. But when I hover it, nothing happens. I want the sub menus to appear on hover.

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown:hover {
  display: block;
}

.nav navbar-nav navbar-left:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="menu-header-menu-left" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left"> <a href="">Dental Services</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown ">

    <ul class="dropdown-menu total-11 sub-left">
      <li><a href="">BLEACHING</a></li>
      <li><a href="">BONE GRAFT</a></li>
      <li><a href="">CHILDREN DENTISTRY</a></li>
      <li><a href="">CLEANING</a></li>

    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

The HTML code for submenu was wrong. You need to start submenu `<ul>` inside parent menu `li`.

Here is an **example**:

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}

#submenu:hover > ul {
  display: block;
 }

.nav navbar-nav navbar-left:hover {

 display:block;

 }
```

```html
<ul id="menu-header-menu-left" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
  <li id="submenu">
    <a href="">Dental Services</a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu total-11 sub-left">
      <li><a href="">BLEACHING</a></li>
      <li><a href="">BONE GRAFT</a></li>
      <li><a href="">CHILDREN DENTISTRY</a></li>
      <li><a href="">CLEANING</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

css

```
.dropdown-menu {position: relative; display: none;} #submenu:hover ul {display: block;} .nav.navbar-nav.navbar-left:hover {display:block;}
```

Html

```
<ul id="menu-header-menu-left" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
```

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu total-11 sub-left">
  <li><a href="">BLEACHING</a></li>
  <li><a href="">BONE GRAFT</a></li>
  <li><a href="">CHILDREN DENTISTRY</a></li>
  <li><a href="">CLEANING</a></li>
</ul>
```